# Computer Cannot Turn On After Hibernate

Tags: memory, windows-8.1, hibernate

English is not my first language, so please forgive me. I have a very old computer. I have used it for several years without any problem until yesterday.

- **Problem:** Could not turn on computer.
- **Brand:** HP.
- **Model:** DC7800P.
- **Processor:** Core2Duo E8300 @2.83GHz.
- **Operating System:** Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit.
- **RAM:** 6 GB DDR2 Dual Channel.
- **RAM Slots:** 4. (Max RAM supported: 8 GB)
- **Monitor:** 2.
- **Graphic Card:** NVIDIA GT730.
- **Cleanliness:** Everything is clean and free of dust. Fans working fine.

**What has happened?**

I'm currently using my computer yesterday. And my wife is cooking cookies. Then my RCCB was kicked (this usually happens when my wife uses the oven). So my house blackout and everything is off including the computer. I turn on back RCCB. I tried to turn on the computer and it can be turned like usual. But because my wife has not finished cooking and worries RCCB will kick back again, I put my computer in hibernate mode and pull out the plug. When my wife finished cooking, I tried to turn on my computer but I no longer able to.

**The solution I have tried**

I have re-seat everything back including RAM, graphic card, cable, and everything. But everything I do cannot turn on my computer back.

The only thing I do that can turn on my computer back is by removing any of 2 pieces of RAM.

For your information, before this happened, I'm using 2 GB/1 GB/2 GB/1 GB in slot 1/2/3/4. But now I only can use max 3 GB of RAM. If I insert more than 3 GB, my computer cannot be turned on.

At first, I thought some of my RAM is damaged. But I have tried them all one by one and it is all working fine. I also try all different kind of slot and it also works fine. It also works fine on any combo of RAM piece as long as it does not exceed 3 GB otherwise my computer cannot be turned on.

If anyone has any thought/experience/suggestion/advice on why I can no longer use more than 3GB, I would truly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SuperUser! What are the symptom(s) you experience when trying to turn on your computer with all the RAM installed? Does the BIOS (manufacturer logo) run? Do you get to the Windows logo with the spinning dots? Does a BSOD happen at some point? Is there any error message?

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini Hi. No because the computer not turning on at all. No fan and nothing. Please check this picture. https://prnt.sc/mtpdr1
Usually on my computer, the left light above microphone will blinking and right light above headphone will always on. 

But now if I insert more than 3GB RAM, computer cannot turn on but both light will only blink once if I push down power button.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound strange but it has saved me many times since the last hurricane we experienced in our environment.

Remove all the RAM and attempt to start the computer. It will do whatever beep codes, etc to tell you there is no RAM. Power the machine down and replace all the RAM and try to start normally. I usually get a message about RAM changing but almost always it fixes my issues. Sounds like a similar situation to your current predicament.

My theory is that the machines get in a weird power state (S1, S3, etc) and cannot figure out how to turn itself back on. The RAM removal resets this condition.

Comment: Hi.. I already remove all RAM and insert it one by one. That is the first thing I did yesterday. But once I add more than 2 pieces of RAM or more than 3GB RAM, my computer cannot turn on at all. No fans spinning, no beep sound and nothing at all. It seems dead :(